# Add ads to android game no xml

Tags: java, android, admob

So I made a game that I'm trying to add ads to but I'm not using any `XML`. I found two examples that say they should work after extensive research and many hours of looking. How ever even when I try implementing that code I still get errors and am at a loss.

I've searched through stack overflow and many other sites and I am at a loss. Ive tried implementing this several different ways and I'm not sure if I'm not including ti right or what.

[image: two remaining errors]

Here are the two remaining errors I'm getting:

The Constructor is not working for the `AdView` class the way its described in the tutorial and I'm not sure how to fix that.

and the AdRequest() function says its implemented as private and even when i try to use the AdRequest().Builder().build(); it still gives the same error.

I have no xml in my code and am using a class that extends SurfaceView for the entire game, and i am using AdMob ads. How do i do this with out xml?

Comment: Checkout examples of how to add admob support here
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I load my ads. Hope it helps.

```
admobAdView = new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView(getActivity());
    admobAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    admobAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-###########/#######");
adViewContainer = (ViewGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.ad_view_group);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("#################")
                .build();
admobAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```